# Android : Calling the methods on UI thread from AsyncTask doInBackground method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using AsyncTask to upload data to UI. i wrote the code to download data from server in a separate method and i am calling that method from doinBackground. It will give error because UI methods can't access from doInBackground.but, i want to access . any alternative process is there to access the UI method from doinBackground.?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> any alternative process is there to access the UI method from doinBackground.?

Call `publishProgress()` in `doInBackground()`. Put your UI-updating logic in `onProgressUpdate()` of your `AsyncTask`. `onProgressUpdate()` will be called on the main application thread (a.k.a., UI thread) after you call `publishProgress()`. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Threads/Asyncer) demonstrating this.

Comment: CommonsWare name is enough . +1 .

Comment: knew the runOnUiThread() way but liked the other approachj of handling this +1.

Comment: Hi i found great answer in the link .Thank you very much

Answer (score 8):

Call **runOnUiThread(Runnable action)**

[more here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8c2c448815010353)

Comment: hi can i call runOnUiThread() from doInBackground .? it will work.? or as usual can i call runOnUiThread from oncreate itself.? here i have one doubt. runOnUiThread will block the UI while uploading data.?

Comment: it makes sense when you call it from doInBackground().. or else it has no meaning..

Comment: you have to write runOnUIThread where you update your main UI.

Answer (score 3):

Use `doInBackground()` just for tasks that :

1. Take some time
2. Are not UI related

Then you can implement `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()` to run code to handle those results on main UI thread from AsyncTask

From JavaDoc for `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()`:

> *"Runs on the UI thread after doInBackground. ... "*

Answer (score 1):

As the others have pointed out, you can use runOnUiThread. But, it seems a little odd that you would want to do that in your doInBackground. If you are wanting to indicate progress to the user you would want to handle that in AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate and call publishProgress in your doInBackground.

You can read more about AsyncTask here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

-Dan